# Common Fishing Policy and Super trawlers

Tags: european-union, fishing

The activity of [Super Trawlers](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2020/aug/13/supertrawlers-ramp-up-activity-uk-protected-waters-during-lockdown) is making the news again given their continued efforts whilst most smaller boats were subject to lockdown restrictions.

Greenpeace is pushing for a ban on supertrawlers stating;

> After Brexit, when the UK leaves the EU common fisheries policy, it will be possible to ban supertrawlers.

The most relevant section of this [older article](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2020/mar/07/ban-supertrawlers-from-uk-waters-after-brexit-say-green-campaigners) states;

> Use of the ships is heavily regulated in some countries, as trawling has been criticised for the physical damage it inflicts on seabeds, but under the common fisheries policy, EU-registered vessels are legally entitled to fish in UK waters, subject to licence conditions, quota allocation and relevant fishing restrictions.

Whilst it seems clear that "super trawlers" as a category of ship cannot be banned from certain zones by the UK and that the quota allocated to each nation can be sold/assigned to any type of ship, is it not possible to affect the same restrictions via licencing and the "relevant restrictions" mentioned in the original article?

Presumably some of the same problems are at the root of the [Scallop Dispute](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-45411941)? As the French could not prevent EU Boats (British in this instance) from fishing in an area they restricted their own fishermen from operating?